# ChartJS non overlapping lines

Tags: chart.js

I have multiple datasets of time based information, such as:

```
{ x: 1502007367658, y: 5},
{ x: 1502007367663, y: 3},
...
```

And

```
{ x: 1502007367653, y: 4},
{ x: 1502007367660, y: 7},
...
```

As you can see, these 2 sets do not overlap in the x axis.

How can I make chartJS show 2 lines with different X values for each?

Currently, I have a full overlap:
[image]

Because this is the code:

```
// 7 Labels, for 7 data points, non linear
this.chart.labels = [newDate(-4), newDate(-3), newDate(2), newDate(3), newDate(4), newDate(5), newDate(6)];
// 3 Datasets
this.chart.datasets = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'},
  {data: [18, 48, 77, 9, 100, 27, 40], label: 'Series C'}
];
```

So is there a way to make each dataset with it's own X axis values?

Answer (score 0):

Giving the dataset's data both X and Y solved the problem. Now it is like:

```
this.chart.datasets = [
  {
    data: [
      { x: newDate(-4), y: 65 },
      { x: newDate(-3), y: 59 },
      { x: newDate(-2), y: 80 }
    ],
    label: 'Series A'
  },
  {
    data: [
      { x: newDate(-3), y: 65 },
      { x: newDate(-2), y: 59 },
      { x: newDate(-1), y: 80 }
    ],
    label: 'Series A'
  },
  {
    data: [
      { x: newDate(-2), y: 65 },
      { x: newDate(-1), y: 59 },
      { x: newDate(0), y: 80 }
    ],
    label: 'Series A'
  }
];
```

[image]